# git return 401 when use authorize token create repository "bad credentials"

Tags: github

when I use follow

```
curl -i -H 'Authorization: token mytoken' https://api.github.com/user/repos -d '{"name":"REPO2"}'
```

return

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Server: GitHub.com
Date: Sat, 04 Mar 2017 16:21:13 GMT
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 93
Status: 401 Unauthorized
X-GitHub-Media-Type: github.v3; format=json
X-RateLimit-Limit: 60
X-RateLimit-Remaining: 57
X-RateLimit-Reset: 1488646926
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: ETag, Link, X-GitHub-OTP, X-RateLimit-Limit, X-RateLimit-Remaining, X-RateLimit-Reset, X-OAuth-Scopes, X-Accepted-OAuth-Scopes, X-Poll-Interval
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'none'
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains; preload
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: deny
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-GitHub-Request-Id: C3B1:3287:955066:BB6710:58BAE978

{
  "message": "Bad credentials",
  "documentation_url": "https://developer.github.com/v3"
}
```

please help me

Comment: The OAuth token you're using is invalid. Are you actually trying to use "mytoken"?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a [personal access token](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line/) in `Settings > Developer settings > Personal access tokens` and select the `repo` scope :

[image]

Then replace it in your request :

```
curl -H 'Authorization: token {0123456789zeaz1224334534}' https://api.github.com/{user}/repos -d '{"name":"REPO2"}'
```

Comment: I use curl -u 'Authorization:my token' https://api.github.com/user/repos -d '{"name":"repo3"}' resolve it 好开心～有没有认识田昊的